# Firestore security rules to allow users to query for a single document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an `email` collection where any user (public) can add a new document with his email.

```
docID: {
  email: 'my@user.com'
}
```

So right now my security rules for the `email` collection is:

```
match /email/{documentID} {
  allow read: if request.auth.token.admin == true;
  allow create: if true;
}
```

**Because I don't want users being able to read other users' emails.**

But I want the client code to able to query for the user's own email, in order to avoid duplicates in my DB. So I want my client code to able to do this:

```
const querySnapshot = await
props.firebase.firestore().collection('email').where('email', '==', email).get();
```

**QUESTION**

How should I write my security rules to achieve that behavior?

I don't want them to be able to query the full `email` collection.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is possible.  Consider instead writing a Cloud Function that takes the email address as input, queries the email collection for it, then returns a boolean to the client indicating if it was present.

Note that this allows anyone to effectively query for any email address, not just "their own" (however you define that ownership).